# How do I change Mario's outfit?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

There is an option after you buy new clothes to change, but how do I change clothes to something I bought previously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There is a closet inside Mario's ship which you can use to change into any purchased outfit.**

Additionally, most stores will have closets which you can use to change clothes.

[image: Mario's hat-shaped ship]

<sub>*The stores in Cap Kingdom, Cascade Kingdom, Wooded Kingdom, and Seaside Kingdom do not have closets</sub>